# Graphviz: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, encoding, graphviz, python-2.x

I try to build the graph using `graphviz`.
I use code to build graph

```
f = Digraph('finite_state_machine', filename='fsm.gv', encoding='utf-8')
f.body.extend(['rankdir=LR', 'size="5,5"'])
f.attr('node', shape='circle')
for i, (id, domain, search_term) in enumerate(zip(ids, domains, search_terms)):
    f.edge(domains[i], domains[i - 1], label=search_terms[i])
f.view()
```

But I get an error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 112: ordinal not in range(128)`.
In `search_terms[i]` contains

```
селена гомес
vk
сын саула
интернет магазин купальников для девочек..
кендалл дженнер
бет зенит
мейвезер
селена гомес
изли ру
американская снайперская винтовка 50 калибра
пятая волна
селена гомес
ютюб
90210 новое поколение
etc
```

How can I check this problem?

Comment: Showing the full error trace would be helpful. Are your strings Unicode strings? If not, you could try to `decode` them first.

Comment: Check out http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: @MarkRansom when I try `decode('utf-8')` I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 0: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: Then that means they're not UTF-8. Try `'mbcs'` instead.

Comment: `Write ASCII and read UTF-8 ?` How to fix byte position on reading ? Read with writing coding method for safely decoding.

Comment: @MarkRansom `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 120: ordinal not in range(128)` too

Comment: OK, `mbcs` is not working on your system. You'll have to figure out what code page your text is in and give it explicitly.

Comment: I use to do it `chardet` and get different code. Some of them are `utf-8`, `ascii`, `windows-1252` etc. I don't know how I can convert it to one encoding to build graph. @MarkRansom